# Set up a socket server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I need a class that will start a socket server and wait for connections. Here is my code:

```
 public static void StatServer()
    {
        TcpClient client;
        TcpListener tcpListener;
        int _serverport = 9898;
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, _serverport);
        try
        {
            tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                if (tcpListener.Pending())
                {
                    client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                    clientThread.Start(client);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

However from the [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), we found that the code doesn't have `TcpClient` etc, which code is correct?
Did I misunderstand the concept?

Comment: If you have never used socket programming I suggest that you do not start now. Instead use a library, for instance mine which is open source: http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/05/griffin-framework-performant-networking-in-net/. It requires just a few lines of code to get a fully working client/server.

Comment: You are busy waiting burning an entire CPU core. I see this mistake a lot. May I ask (out of curiosity) why you decided to check `Pending` before accepting?

Comment: -@usr, I don't know. I haven't touched this area. My boss gave me the piece of code. Any improvement?

Comment: Delete the check. Accept blocks until there is something to accept. In general, using sockets without understanding every line is very dangerous. Unsound development practice in general if I may say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, both are correct. I think, TcpListener/client is just a kind of a wrapper, it uses Socket inside it.

Just looked though decompiled code of TcpListener

```
private Socket m_ServerSocket;

...

public TcpListener(IPEndPoint localEP)
{
  if (Logging.On)
    Logging.Enter(Logging.Sockets, (object) this, "TcpListener", (object) localEP);
  if (localEP == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("localEP");
  this.m_ServerSocketEP = localEP;
  this.m_ServerSocket = new Socket(this.m_ServerSocketEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  if (!Logging.On)
    return;
  Logging.Exit(Logging.Sockets, (object) this, "TcpListener", (string) null);
}
```

and so on.

TcpListener, I think, provides some comfortable methods for you, Socket is more low-level.

Comment: Incorrect. Both TcpListener and TcpClient exist in .NET

Comment: heh. I misread the answer (did not read the first two lines correctly ;))